# How to post a file to django WITHOUT using html form

Tags: python, django, post, file-upload

I'm currently trying to post a file to a service endpoint, written in django.

I can find a bunch of examples like this ([exert from here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/?from=olddocs)):

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
     ........
```

but how do I make a request using either the [test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/?from=olddocs#module-django.test.client) or [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) which can pass files to the server *when it isn't coming from an HTML form?*  I'm currently trying to urlencode the file contents into a json string and then pass that along; but that is proving to be cumbersome.

**IN ADDITION TO ANSWER BELOW**:

1. Don't forget to make your service csrf exempt
2. Don't set the content type or set it explicitly to multipart.
3. [Consult this for info on how to handle incoming files in your view.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/?from=olddocs#handling-uploaded-files)

Comment: I recommend this library http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Goin says, with [`Requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html), you could do this:

```
>>> r = requests.post('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.headers['content-type']
'application/json; charset=utf8'
>>> r.encoding
'utf-8'
>>> r.text
u'{"type":"User"...'
>>> r.json
{u'private_gists': 419, u'total_private_repos': 77, ...}
```

This in `urllib2` would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib2

gh_url = 'https://api.github.com'

req = urllib2.Request(gh_url)

password_manager = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
password_manager.add_password(None, gh_url, 'user', 'pass')

auth_manager = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_manager)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_manager)

urllib2.install_opener(opener)

handler = urllib2.urlopen(req)

print handler.getcode()
print handler.headers.getheader('content-type')
```

Source: [`github`](https://gist.github.com/973705)

Posting a multipart-encoded file would be easy in requests. From the official docs:

```
>>> url = '/your/recieving/end'
>>> files = {'report.xls': open('report.xls', 'rb')}

>>> r = requests.post(url, files=files)
>>> r.text # response json
```

Comment: How could I use this to post a file/contents of a file to a django service?  Also, what would the view look like which parses the file from the response?

Comment: Sadly, I don't know django much :( .. but check my update to the answer. Is that the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: I think you've gotten me closer.  I didn't know about the `opener`s in urllib2, so I'm looking into that now.

Comment: Actually, I think I get it know.  I'll give it a shot and accept assuming it works for me.

Comment: Thanks again!  I've updated my answer with a little extra info needed to tie all of this together but it works like a charm.